# AngularJS: Function call on ngSwipeLeft

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swipe

Title pretty much explains it all. Inputting ngSwipeLeft="someFunction()" does not seem to work as I hoped it would. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but what are your ideas? [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft) is the documentation for ngSwipeLeft.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eaSCqNzu5TRcT0lPE5lv?p=preview)

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: We can't tell if you're doing it wrong unless you provide more details ;)  For example, are you including the ng-touch module in your application?

Comment: @SunilD. Yes, sorry about that. I have updated the question with an example. Thanks, and yes I am including the ng-touch module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to do is create a controller for that javascript, and then work off of its scope.

```
<div ng-show="!showActions" data-ng-swipe-left="someFunction()">
Some list content, like an email in the inbox
</div>
<div ng-show="showActions" data-ng-swipe-right="someFunction()">">
<button ng-click="reply()">Reply</button>
<button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
$scope.showActions = false;

$scope.someFunction = function () {
   $scope.showActions = !$scope.showActions;
};
```

That is how I do it in my applications. I hope it helps.

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/d5VyDWcHul6aKPvRYMk1?p=preview).

The plunk works but it is a little off. It sometimes highlights instead of switching over. It works best when swiping to the right side.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for! Cheers. One question though, what does the data do before ng-swipe-left/right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you talking about the showActions state? Or some other part of the javascript?

Comment: I was just talking about "data-ng-swipe-right" when you do not have the "data-" part in the Plunk

Comment: Oh, I see. That is just a HTML 5 convention I try to use. I'm not sure where I picked it up from and sometimes I forget. In Visual Studio it is very useful for bringing up intellisense. I just modified your code quickly with the plunk so I didn't bother with the data- part. Overall the code tends to work with data- or not in the directives.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div>
            <div>
                <pre> Left swipes: {{model.left}}</pre>
            </div>
            <div>
                <pre>Right swipes: {{model.right}}</pre>
            </div>
            <div>
                <pre>Touch clicks: {{model.click}} </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swipy"
            ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft()"
            ng-swipe-right="swipeRight()"
            ng-click="touchClick()">
            Swipe me !
        </div>
    </div>

<style type="text/css">
    div {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }

    div.swipy {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 3px groove gray;
        background-color: light-gray;
    }

</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.model = {
            left:  0,
            right: 0,
            click: 0
        };
        $scope.swipeLeft = function () {
            $scope.model.left += 1;
        };
        $scope.swipeRight = function () {
            $scope.model.right += 1;
        };
        $scope.touchClick = function () {
            $scope.model.click += 1;
        };
    });

</script>
```